# GitCommandNotFound in python git library

Tags: python, git, unix

This script I've created on my local windows machine works fine.

```
import git    
repo = C:/user/folder/repo
g = git.cmd.Git(repo)
g.execute("git config --get remote.origin.url")
```

But if I try to run it in our unix server(ofc I changed the repo directory), I'm getting

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 735, in execute
    raise GitCommandNotFound(command, err) from err
git.exc.GitCommandNotFound: Cmd('git') not found due to: FileNotFoundError('[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'git config --get remote.origin.url': 'git config --get remote.origin.url'')
```

Based on the gitPython documentation

> exceptiongit.exc.GitCommandNotFound(command, cause) Thrown if we
> cannot find the git executable in the PATH or at the path given by the
> GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE environment variable

So I've tried adding the git to PATH. 
vi ~/.bashrc

```
export GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/git/__init__.py
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME:${LDCONFIG_HOME}:$GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE
```

but it's still not working

Comment: do you have actual git on your PATH? what happans when you open a terminal and type `git`?

Comment: Your script line `repo = C:/user/folder/repo` indicates that you seem to be using Windows, not UNIX as the tag `unix` would imply. Did you install Git for Windows? Did you select that you want to be able to run Git commands from WIndows CMD? Please [edit] your question to answer.

Comment: Hi @Bodo, I've changed the value of repo to unix directory.

Comment: @Nullman git is installed in the unix server. running git --version returns git version 1.8.3.1

Comment: Are you able to call `git` via terminal on your unix server?

Comment: @Koenigsberg yes I'm able to call git. running git --version returns git version 1.8.3.1

Comment: Is this true for any directory on your unix system, or just some specific one?

Comment: @Koenigsberg you mean git working on any directory on my unix server? Yes, it works in any directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reading the [documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=git.cmd.Git#git.cmd.Git.execute) it appears that execute uses `subprocess.Popen` in which case it simply doesn't have your environment. you have several ways to address this, either use the `env` keyword with a dictionary containing your PATH, or pass `shell=True` (which is dangerous if user code can reach here)
so either do:

```
g.execute("git config --get remote.origin.url", env=os.environ)
```

or

```
g.execute("git config --get remote.origin.url", shell=True)
```

Comment: sorry, but do you have a sample on how to use the env keyword? I'm new to python so I'm not very familiar with it

Comment: i'll try using the env keyword. why is using shell=True dangerous? Is it possible that it could mess up my unix server if I use it?

Comment: @user2058738 its only dengerous if you dont control the what goes into `g.execute`. "dengerous" means that if a user supplies the string you run he can then run arbitrary code (so danger here is from the perspective of security)

Comment: I see. So env=os.environ did not work but shell=True did. I understood now what you meant by "dangerous". I think on my case it would be fairly safe as only few devs has access on the unix machine. I'll still explore on how to make the env keyword work but I'm already accepting this as the correct answer. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

These worked for me. :-

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/git
export GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/git
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="/usr/bin/ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```